# Check an input value before submission

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form and before the submission I'd like to check if the form was completed by a bot. I added some invisible fields to the form and I want to check if they were fulfilled. If yes, then it means that a spambot did it.

However the IF statement after in the addEventListener, when the submit button is clicked, doesn't work.

I expect to go through the if statement before the form will be POST

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  window.addEventListener(
    "load",
    function() {

      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("validity");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";

      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener(
          "submit",
          function(event) {

            let hiddenBox = document.getElementById('nameFake').value
            let trimmedHiddenBox = hiddenBox.trim()

            if (trimmedHiddenBox.length == 0) {
              //I change the background to check if the IF statement is checked at all
              document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
              // the length is 0, it means that it was not completed by a bot and the form can do POST
            } else {
              event.preventDefault();
              document.body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
            }
          },
          false
        );
      });
    },
    false
  );
});
```

```html
<form class="validity" name="webForm" id="webForm">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>


  <label class="ohnohoney" for="namefake"></label>
  <input class="ohnohoney" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="namefake" name="namefake" placeholder="Your fake name here">
  <label class="ohnohoney" for="countryfake"></label>
  <input class="ohnohoney" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="namefake" name="countryfake" placeholder="Your fake name here">
```

Comment: I notice your element has the ID `namefake` but your `getElementById` is doing `nameFake`. Maybe it's just a capitalization typo? You also have two items with the same ID which is illegal in HTML and may impact the ability to query the element.

Comment: I think the second one is supposed to be `countryfake` to match the label.

Comment: I think you should call `event.preventDefault()` in the `if` block, not `else`.

Comment: Thanks! The elementID caused the issue :). Problem solved